# What is the maximum timeout for a contract that you can define in Marlowe?

Tags: marlowe, smart-contract

We know that Marlowe contracts always end mandatorily because a maximum timeout is defined. I wonder what the maximum timeout is, it seems like you can put a huge epoch/slot in which would be practically "infinite".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that the duration of a Marlowe contract could be practically "infinite": there is no specific limit on the timeout slot for a [Marlowe contract](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/marlowe/src/Language/Marlowe/Semantics.hs).

Comment: What is your source? The link you provided is not specific enough to qualify as an answer.

Comment: (1) [`Timeout` can be any slot number](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/6d1a06a373ebaf8fd8408f23c9d72f96d922bbaf/marlowe/src/Language/Marlowe/Semantics.hs#L106), (2) [the Marlowe state machine does not impose any limits on the slot number](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/6d1a06a373ebaf8fd8408f23c9d72f96d922bbaf/marlowe/src/Language/Marlowe/Client.hs#L487), and (3) [the Marlowe redeem code](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/6d1a06a373ebaf8fd8408f23c9d72f96d922bbaf/marlowe/src/Language/Marlowe/Client.hs#L244) does not either.